# Can I choose a preferred (Siri / communications) device?

Tags: macos, iphone, ipad, siri, facetime

I have an iPhone, an iPad, an iMac, and a HomePod. When I say "Hey Siri", if all or some of the devices are close, they all try to answer. If I get a FaceTime call, they all ring.

Is there a way to prioritize these devices, for example, when I have all these devices in one place, to say I want to only hear my computer ring. When I'm using my HomePod, to filter my phone and iPad, so they don't try to answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your devices communicate with each other over Bluetooth to determine which devices respond to "Hey Siri". If you experience that they all answer, you should observe the [following](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208472):

- Ensure that Bluetooth is turned on
- Ensure that all devices are updated
- Ensure that "Hey Siri" is turned on in Siri settings on all devices

Regarding phone calls, there's no way of prioritising devices automatically here unfortunately.

You can manually turn devices on/off by opening the Settings app on your phone, select Phone and select "Calls on Other Devices" - from here you can enable/disable calls on your various devices.